# React suddenly responding with index.html instead of javascript imports

Tags: reactjs, import, create-react-app, web-worker, webassembly

Recently I've been unable to load javascript scripts to my webworkers in react for some reason. It always responds with index.html.

My config is simply a standard create-react-app app. The screenshots are from my actual project but I have confirmed that the problem persists if I create a new project and try to initialize a minimal example.

Each ffmpeg.* file is affected. This is also not specific to ffmpeg since another library had the same issue - thankfully the initialization of that library is simpler so I was able to simply put that libraries worker-file in the public folder - and that worked.

It might be a stupid question but I'm really at my wits end here and I can't figure out how to investigate further.

Thank you <3

**EDIT:**
It works if I put all the files it is trying to hit in the public folder - so it has to be some kind of context issue(??) This seems like a really stupid way to go about it. It's not in a worker at the point of loading - it's the worker loader that fails to access the stuff it needs in the node_modules folder, (core script, worker script and wasm code). Whet?

[image: console]

[image: response]

[image: network tab of request]

Comment: Also - this EXACT setup worked days ago - no change in the configuration. Now it just doesn't. halp pls.

Comment: Can you manually hit the file in the browser?

Comment: @Raythe by fetching it or navigating to the url?

Comment: navigating to the url

Comment: @Raythe well tried both - neither works :) fetching gives me the index.html, visiting doesn't give me the file either.

Comment: What if you try to navigate to something in that same directory that doesn't exist?  I would expect a 404 error.  What are you using for a webserver?

Comment: It's the standard create-react-app configuration - node server with webpack. It doesn't 404 since it's configured as a single-page app. It just doesn't do anything at all. It loads nothing. I would have to explicitly define it to navigate to some 404 document.

Comment: @polisen Did you ever manage to resolve this, I have the same issue, and have spent far too long trying to figure this out?